# Multiple touch when scrolling in TableView (change speed or direction)

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm in the latest step of my TableView and I have a very simple problem: I would like to scroll (for example) direction to top and when I touch again the table (direction to bottom) it change the direction of the scroll.

At the moment, the problem is when I scroll to the bottom I can't scroll to top until the animation is finished.

**Question:**
How can I enable multi touch in my table view in order to change the direction of the scroll while the animation isn't finished?

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Comment: Can you please post the code that is handling the animation?

Comment: I haven't got any code @Mika, I'm just using the default animation scroll from the TableViewController. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is having the same problem, the solution is modify the animateWithDuration in the willDisplayCell:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Define the initial state (Before the animation)
    cell.alpha = 0.25

    // Define the final state (After the animation)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { cell.alpha = 1 }, completion: nil)
}
```

The problem was the animation in my table cell.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do to stop an animation in progress is the following:

```
table.layer.removeAllAnimations()
```

Then you can start the new animation! Easy as pie!

Comment: Hi @Mika, I have to assign a GestureRecognizer to my TableView? Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: I'm just asking, this is my first time trying to change the behaviour of the scroll because I would like to make it cool.

Comment: Yes. Just add a gesture recogniser at the bottom and make it removeAllAnimations and then do what you want

Comment: Hi @Mika, so, I have to add the GestureRecognizer to my table view, and after that? Regards,